# Couldn't return papers to border officials last time. Should I be afraid when going back to USA?

Tags: visas, usa, legal, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

Three years ago I was on holidays in Canada and visited the Niagara Falls. I also went to the American side of the falls and got something like a "short-term visa". I also got a green paper with all my information (name, passport number, etc.) which I should give back at the border when leaving USA again.

When I got back from the USA side of the falls, the border was abandoned. Therefore I couldn't give the green paper back to the officials. Now I'm really a bit afraid that in their computer system I still haven't left the USA.

Next summer I plan to visit USA again. Can I get into trouble at the border?

Comment: I cannot prove this, but I think you are **way** over-estimating the competence of the US government. They probably don't know, they almost certainly don't care. Of course, it isn't me that has to go through customs.

Comment: @Malvolio: I would definitely agree before 9/11 but now all bets are off ...

Comment: @hippietrail -- Because panic and over-reaction makes government bureaucracies *more* competent?  I would take ESultanik's advice and have the documentation that you returned home *with you*, and show it to them if they ask.  It seems less risky than drawing attention to yourself by filing ahead of time.  Again, just what *I* would do, you have to make your decisions.

Comment: Yes I'm not certain enough of anything to give an answer, only comments. I've had my run-ins with US immigration in the past, including being denied access at the border. Like I said "all bets are off". I wouldn't bet it's definitely OK and I wouldn't bet it's definitely not OK. They're still a huge clunky bureaucracy but especially immigration officials do not play nice, in my own country either. Incompetence can go both ways too and I've been denied at a border crossing of another country due to just that. ESultanik has a great answer though.

Comment: From what I've heard, individual US immigration officers have a lot of discretion as to whom they allow in.  Therefore, a lot of it comes down to random chance as to which officer deals with your case.  If you can convince him or her that you didn't overstay your previous visa (with proper documentation), then I think you will be fine.  Also, given the US's clunky bureaucracy, you could plausibly make the claim that you previously sent the green form to Kentucky and it's not your fault that it hasn't been processed yet; the website I linked states that they don't sent confirmations of receipt.

Comment: Funny enough I just came back from the states. It wasn't a problem to get into it, but now I have again this stupid green form left in my passport.

Comment: Have a look at someone who is already a step further: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17053/11886

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49393/how-do-i-clear-an-incorrect-red-flag-on-my-us-visa-for-overstaying-when-in-fact

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes, according to the official rules you could be denied access at the border.  You can avoid this by submitting the green form (along with additional documentation) after the fact.

---

Most I-94s these days are recorded electronically.  Before sending in your evidence as described below, check your electronic records at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov; if your departure was recorded correctly, you don't need to do anything.

---

It sounds like you participated in the [Visa Waiver Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program) and the green form was an [I-94W](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_I-94).

[According to the US Government](http://www.uscis.gov/portal/site/uscis/menuitem.5af9bb95919f35e66f614176543f6d1a/?vgnextoid=e5d95d4c6608e010VgnVCM1000000ecd190aRCRD),

> If you departed by land, private vessel or private plane, **you will need to take steps to correct the record**. If you do not validate your timely departure from the United States, or, if you cannot reasonably prove you departed within the time frame given to you when you entered, the next time you apply for admission to the U.S., Customs and Border Protection (CBP) may conclude you remained in the U.S. beyond your authorized stay. If this happens, **your visa may be subject to cancellation or you may be returned immediately to your foreign point of origin**.
> <sub>[Emphasis is mine.]</sub>

If you still have the green form, you can remedy the situation by mailing it to:

> Coleman Data Solutions
> Box 7965
> Akron, OH 44306
> Attn: NIDPS (I-94)
> USA

if using the U.S. Postal Service, or

> Coleman Data Solutions
> 3043 Sanitarium Road, Suite 2
> Akron, OH  44312
> Attn: NIDPS (I-94)
> USA

if using FedEx or UPS.

You should also include a copy of the boarding pass you used to exit Canada.  You should also provide a letter explaining your situation and why the form was not originally collected.  Proof that you lived elsewhere after the 90 day period of the visa waiver (*e.g.*, rent checks, pay stubs, receipts, *&c.*, from after you got home) would also be helpful.

[Note that the visa waiver program also counts time you spent in Canada and Mexico](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=90989&start=252).  Therefore, you will need to show that your total time spent in Canada and the USA was no longer than 90 days.

The [original US government FAQ page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94) does seem to suggest that it may be enough to simply bring this documentation with you the next time you enter the US.  Regardless of whether or not you mail it to the government in advance, you should definitely bring a copy of all of the documentation with you on re-entry.  Also, if you are really worried, it seems like you will have no problems if you apply for and receive a formal tourist visa before re-entering the US, but that process will also likely require you to provide the same documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Denied Access would be not so bad than being arrested or something like this ;)

Comment: Apparently, the address has changed, see https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/752/~/i-still-have-my-i-94

Comment: Does the VWP count the time in Canada before you first entered the US and after you last exited? I was under the impression the time in Canada only mattered if you were in the US, then in Canada, and then wanted to *return* to the US before going back home.

Comment: @cpast I'm not sure offhand.  That would be a good question to ask separately on this site.