# How do I correct missing departure records?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, i-94

I am a Canadian citizen. A few years ago, I had a four-month internship in the US. I entered on a J1 visa. After completing it and returning to Canada, I subsequently did two more four-month internships, both on J1 visas as well. However, when I returned from the second internship, I completely forgot to turn in my I-94 card. When heading to the US for my third internship, the CBP agent obviously noticed this, gave me a big lecture on how I screwed up, almost turned me back home, etc.; nonetheless, he still admitted me and I completed my third internship, making sure to hand in the I-94 card this time.

Some time later, I went to the US for a short vacation. For some reason, I was pulled aside again for I-94 issues, even though I turned in my latest I-94 card. This almost caused me to miss a connecting flight.

I then found that there's an online database where you can check your arrival and departure records. To my surprise, it indicates that there are still *two* missing departure records, despite the fact that I am in possession of zero I-94 forms (I turned it in after internships #1 and #3, and the CBP agent took the one from internship #2):

```
                   Departure    2013 June 14        MIL - MILWAUKEE, WI
Vacation      -->  Arrival      2013 June 08        CHI - DISTRICT OFFICE 9, CHICAGO, IL
                   Departure    2012 December 23    SFR - SAN FRANCISCO, CA
Internship #3 -->  Arrival      2012 August 25      TOR - TORONTO, ONT. CANADA
Internship #2 -->  Arrival      2011 December 31    TOR - TORONTO, ONT. CANADA
Internship #1 -->  Arrival      2011 April 28       TOR - TORONTO, ONT. CANADA
```

I fear that these missing departure records will haunt me every time I try to travel to the US. How can I correct the missing records, even if I don't have the I-94 forms anymore? I still have all of my original boarding passes for the missing departures (all trips were done via air).

Comment: Seems similar, but I'm particularly interested in the case where I don't even have the I-94 forms anymore -- would I still send my other documents (boarding passes, etc.) as evidence in absence of the I-94 forms?

Comment: @JeffE yes you would.  And photocopies of passport stamps, if Canada stamps the passports of entering Canadians.  You can also bring that evidence with you when you travel to the US.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49393/how-do-i-clear-an-incorrect-red-flag-on-my-us-visa-for-overstaying-when-in-fact

Answer (score 0):

The I-94 history was only made electronic like 2014 so I couldn't fix earlier years but despite many arrivals and departures missing and some departures are recorded on completely fictious dates a) I haven't had problems crossing the US border b) I even got a NEXUS card (I am a Canadian permanent resident). So: don't worry.