# How can I re-enter the US if my VWP expired in Mexico

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, mexico

I'm from Belgium and I'm traveling by car from Canada to Patagonia (Argentina).
I left the USA just in time (90days) but I got my visa from Mexico 1 day 
after my (90days) VWP expires. 
My plan is to drive to Patagonia and come back to the USA in 6 months.

Will it be a problem if they see at the US airport that I got my Mexican visa after my US VWP was already expired?

I left within the 90 days. I have an I-94A visa so the date on my passport is the day I have to leave. I crossed the border by car around 7pm but I wasn't able to stop at the border so I drove to Ensenada (because they have an immigration office there as well). But that office was closed so I had to wait another day. So that's why my Mexican visa has 1 day difference with my VWP and I'm not sure if that's a big problem if I come back to the US after 6 months. Technically I left the US within the 90 days but will they check when I got my Mexican visa?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying. You seem to be saying you left the US by going to Mexico the day your VWP expires? (Note that the date of expiry should be "89 days" from the date of entry because the 90 days includes the entire days of entry and departure.) But they you said you got a Mexican visa one day later? How is that possible? You entered Mexico before you got a Mexican visa?

Comment: Also, you know that there are no roads to drive from Central America into South America, right? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap)

Comment: @user102008 he could have flown via say, Jamaica (transit) to Mexico and gotten a visa  when arriving say, 30 hours after the US, in Mexico.

Comment: So you drove? Did you cross 2 min before midnight or something, for this to occur?

Comment: What did you do with the I-94W? You were supposed to turn this in at the border when you left.

Comment: I still have the paper

Comment: You need to [do this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2026/3221)

Comment: Is your Mexican entry stamp on the day you left or the day after you left? Because you need some proof that you were outside the US some time on the day you left, and if you don't have an entry stamp on that day, then you need to find something else, or it will be a problem.

Comment: My Mexican stamp is a day after I left the States. I went to the immigration office in Ensenada but is was already closed.
The only proof I have from leaving the usa in time is a ticket of a toll road that has the time and date. And I can proof the office in Ensenada closes at 5pm.
But that's all I have. You think that's enough?

Comment: @quinten I think it is enough.

Comment: I think what is happening is that Mexico allows foreigners from certain countries to visit the "border zone" for less than 72 hours without getting another document. And if they need to travel further into Mexico, they need to get a document called an FMM at an immigration office (at the border or elsewhere). The OP crossed the border, but got the FMM on a later date. The OP was inspected when they crossed the border, but they don't always stamp passports on entry. If they OP didn't specifically request they stamp the passport, the OP may have no proof of having entered Mexico on that date.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a problem for you. Since you did leave within your 90 days, and you have a reasonable explanation for the later date of your Mexican visa, there shouldn't be any problems on return to the US.  They're more likely to have questions for you about what you were doing in South America.

Comment: Technically he *didn't* overstay - he left within the 90 days, no?

Comment: @MarkMayo: Oh, perhaps I misread. The missing piece is perhaps where he was on the day *after* his VWP expired. Not enough information to determine.

Comment: yeah, I've commented asking about this. It's possible if he flew somewhere first (Transit) or if he crossed at 2 min to midnight and then  got the visa 5 min later, but as you say, not enough info at present :/

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying.
I left within the 90 days. I have an I-94W visa so the date on my passport is the day I have to leave. 
I crossed the border by car around 7pm but I wasn't able to stop at the border so I drove to Ensenada (because they have an immigration office there as well. But that office was close so I had to wait another day. 
So that's why my Mexican visa has 1 day difference with my VPW and I'm not sure if that's a big problem if I come back to the us after 6 months.
Technically I left the us within the 90 days but will they check when I got my Mexican visa?

Comment: @quinten: Thanks for the detail. I've edited my answer. It would be helpful if you add this additional info to your question too.

Comment: I've add the info to my question ;)