# How boat traveller's stay duration is tracked in USA?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

I came to the USA by the plane and got 180 days to stay(B1/B2 visa). Then I was travelling exactly 180 days around the USA on the sailboat. And left the country from Key West to Cuba on the sailboat. I didn't inform anybody I'm leaving the country.
In [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96019/can-i-re-enter-the-usa-after-a-1-day-overstay-3-years-ago) I see the difficulties that can happen due to an overstay. As I understand, airlines inform the US government.
How stay duration is tracked in my case?

**Update 1:**
@Crazydre gave a good explanation what to do if something wrong. Thanks, this is very useful. But my question was: **How stay duration is tracked for such cases?**

**Update 2:**
This question is purely theoretical as I entered to USA 4 times after this. But before each entrance I wondered and worried about how my staying was tracked.

Comment: Be aware that travelling direct from the US to Cuba by private sailboat may cause you trouble. I'm unaware if the recent relaxation changes these restrictions, but at one point you could certainly be in trouble for doing this.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm unaware that such restrictions exist (other than for US citizens and permanent residents).  Do you have a reference?

Comment: The references I have look like they are out of date now. This may not be a problem any more.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I think this is(was) true for US citizens. I had no problems when returned to USA several times after.

Comment: With regard to update 1: the answer to your question is that the exit is not tracked unless the traveler follows the procedure outlined in Crazydre's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you're back home from your travels (or now, if you're long-term travelling), you have to gather the following materials:

- a printout of the result page of [this search](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/recent-search)
- a photocopy of your passport ID page, the page with the US visa and the page with the US entry stamp;
- photocopies of **all** passport stamps obtained since leaving the US (and in particular the Cuban entry stamp)
- any original tickets that you may have since leaving the US (after making copies for your own record);
- A dated bank statement showing all transactions since leaving the US.
- Any dated original receipts obtained since leaving the US.
- A letter explaining in detail your entire trip, stating the date and place of exit from the US, and asking for the exit to be added to the electronic I94.

Send all these materials by registered mail to:

> Coleman Data Solutions
>
> Box 7965
>
> Akron, OH 44306
>
> Attn: NIDPS (I-94)
>
> USA

If the evidence is deemed to be sufficient, the record (found [**here**](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search)) will be updated, so check it from time to time. Note that Coleman don't respond to any communication.

If, for any reason, the record is not corrected within two months (check regularly), then gather all the above mentioned evidence (except the passport copy and explanation letter) and bring them on your next trip to the US for presentation at the border, so that the record can be retroactively corrected. However, only do this as a last resort, because if you're unlucky enough to get the wrong officer on re-entry, you may well be refused entry and blacklisted in the immigration records in spite of any evidence you present, although as you hold a visa, you can appeal to an immigration judge if it comes down to it.

Comment: What is the Coleman and how it is related to US Government?

Comment: @elshev Coleman is a private but non-profit firm which holds this document processing contract with the State Department; you will find the same contact information from [official sources](https://ch.usembassy.gov/visas/nonimmigrant-visas/94-departure-card/). They are a unit of [Coleman Professional Services](http://www.colemanservices.org/), a non-profit based in Ohio.